# Systemd: Enabled service (simple loop) is dead

Tags: systemd

I have a simple jiggle script to prevent a machine from logging off.

```
# /home/fny/jiggle.sh
randint() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: randint <max>"
    return 1
  fi
  expr $(tr -dc 0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 10) % $(expr $1 + 1)
}

while :; do
  if [ $(xprintidle) -gt 60000 ]; then # if idle longer than 1 min
    x=$(randint 500)
    y=$(randint 500)
    echo "jiggling to $x $y"
    xdotool mousemove $x $y
  fi
  sleep 300 # check every 5 minutes
done
```

I decided to turn it into a simple jiggle service:

```
# /home/fny/.config/systemd/user/jiggle.service
[Unit]
Description=jiggle

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/fny/jiggle.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I performed the required systemctl incantations:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable jiggle
systemctl --user start jiggle
```

I decided to check on my service. It is enabled but dead. Why?

```
systemctl --user status jiggle

● jiggle.service - jiggle
     Loaded: loaded (/home/fny/.config/systemd/user/jiggle.service; enabled>
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: If you didn't get any error output by using `systemctl --user status jiggle.service` try running: `journalctl -xe --user --unit jiggle.service`

Comment: Is the service `inactive (dead)` directly after you have enabled/started the service or after you have rebooted the system?

Apart of that: As your script depends on the graphical interface, you might want to set `WantedBy=graphical.target`.

You can list your targets with `systemctl list-units --type=target` and your current target with `systemctl get-default`.

Comment: Note that X11 programs like `xdotool` need an environment holding values for DISPLAY, and perhaps XAUTHORITY. A systemd user unit does not have these by default. See `systemctl --user show-environment` for what is in the env. (This doesnt explain why the service is dead).

Comment: This is after a restart. `systemtl --user show-environment` has a display set. Some journal output: Oct Oct 01 01:58:54 MACHINE sh[1244709]: jiggling to 20 126
Oct 01 02:03:54 MACHINE sh[1260140]: tr: write error: Broken pipe
Oct 01 02:03:54 MACHINE sh[1260140]: tr: write error
Oct 01 02:03:54 MACHINE sh[1260146]: tr: write error: Broken pipe
Oct 01 02:03:54 MACHINE sh[1244709]: jiggling to 134 453

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. According to [this answer](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2690#issuecomment-186973730):

> There is no multi-user.target in --user mode. User services should by WantedBy=default.target.

So you have two options to can run the service successfully.

1. Changing to `WantedBy=default.target.`:

```bash
# /home/fny/.config/systemd/user/jiggle.service
[Unit]
Description=jiggle

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/fny/jiggle.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

2. Use the systemd service as *system service* and not *user service*. First, you will have to copy your `jiggle servicce` in `/etc/systemd/system` and instead of using `systemctl --user enable jiggle` you should use `sudo systemctl enable jiggle`. And it's recommendable to use `WantedBy=graphical.target` because you are using software which depends of a GUI session:

```bash
#/etc/systemd/system/jiggle.service
[Unit]
Description=jiggle

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/fny/jiggle.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

I've tested those services on Redhat 9.0 and it works successfully.